# Messaing.sendEmail intermitent exception: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, there are no stores that currently contain the extent

Tags: apex

On an org now on na56 (i.e. was migrated this weekend with the org split), I am now getting intermittent errors on code that previously worked before that did an apex email send using `Messaging.sendEmail`.

The exception is:

> First exception on row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, there are no stores that currently contain the extent= F00Di0000000KlMj0KE3100000H5NI21, so we can't read it!: []

Is anybody else seeing this issue?